# is there a command that kills all horses and nothing else?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

is there a command that kills all horses and nothing else

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.  They'll just end up getting closed.

Comment: sorry its just no one did a good answer

Comment: then, @alixey999, that means one of three things. Either your question is not of a good enough quality, it has a duplicate with a working answer somewhere else, or you have not waited long enough.

Comment: @Frank Can you even close a question as a dupe of another dupe?

Comment: @Studoku Indeed.  We probably shouldn't, though.  The question's been modified, but it's along exactly the same lines as previous questions, and displays no effort.

Comment: @Frank The question we're claiming it's a dupe of has no satisfactory answers. The answers to the one that's a dupe of are not going to help OP.

Comment: @Studoku Again, check the original revision; when this was asked, it was a dupe of his previous question.  Either way, though, since this question has been edited, it's not a dupe of either of them.

Comment: Please stop changing you question completely please, it'll just confuse people.

Comment: Once you've gotten answers to your question, it's extremely rude to change it to something else.  I have rolled it back so that you don't invalidate your answers.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

To **kill all horses and nothing else**, as your question currently asks, use this command:

```
/kill @e[type=EntityHorse]
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/kill @e[type=horse]`

Answer (score 0):

In 1.8, `@e` was added. `@p` targets the closest player, `@a` targets all players, `@r` targets a random player, and `@e` targets all entities. Entities in Minecraft include things like all mobs, primed TNT, XP Orbs, falling sand, items on the ground, etc. If you want to kill all entities, us 
`/kill @e`
However, `@e` does take arguments to specify what you want to kill. You do this with a `[type=]` argument. If you want to kill every zombie in the world, use `/kill @e[type=Zombie]` 
In your case, you want to kill all horses, so you'd use the command `/kill @e[type=EntityHorse]`. This can be applied to any entity in a world that you want to kill.